# AngularJS Is there a viewRendered event after route changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there anything like viewRendered event. I like to do a generic manipulation for any view after its has been loaded with jQuery.

```
$rootScope.$on("$viewRendered"...
```

Comment: The way angularjs works one can never ascertain when the view is rendered completely. $timeout is your best bet for this requirement

Comment: $timeout is a little bit hacky. Too bad.

Comment: But $timeout not always correct. some time it may take more than as $timeout then you will get error.

Comment: @Nitish Kumar like i said above. the question is already answered with "The way angularjs works one can never ascertain when the view is rendered completely"

Comment: @Nitish Kumar but thanks for your help anyway

Comment: $http doing same thing which you want in url part put your template url. it will work. i am doing this way and its working fine

Comment: its only loads the view into the function scope. but it will not manipulate the actual view on the website. i will try it anyway thanks.